# Error in transfer form eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am transferring my Android App from eclipse to Android Studio.

However, I am encountering the following error.

```
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name  'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':myproject:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/myPath/Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

My build.gradle is the following.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/adstirwebview.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.2.jar')
}
```

I guess the following parts cause above errors.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

However I have no idea what to do. Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

you are using the latest version with has a dependency with support libraries v23 which require **api 23 to compile**.

Use:

```
  compileSdkVersion 23
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would like to set compileSdkVersion to 21 because I use Apache HTTP Client which is not able to use in API23...

Comment: @supermonkey In this case you can use this: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client or you can use okHttp library. Otherwise use the version 7.8.0 of google play service but it is not a good idea to use old libraries only to avoid the apache issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand. When I set compileSdkVersion to 23, "compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'"causes error. Should I replace it to what?

Comment: Use the latest stable com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 and edit the question with the new issue.